# Wiremock - "URL does not match" even though it is same

Tags: java, wiremock

I am facing an issue that Wiremock says my URLs don't match even though they are the same. Obviously I am missing something. What am I doing wrong?

```
WireMock.stubFor(WireMock.get(WireMock.urlPathEqualTo("/test/url?bookingCode=XYZ123&lastName=TEST"))
    .willReturn(WireMock.aResponse()
    .withStatus(200))
)
```

Below is the console log.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Closest stub                                             | Request                                                  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                           |
GET                                                        | GET
/test/url?bookingCode=XYZ123&lastName=TEST                 | /test/url?bookingCode=XYZ123&lastName=TEST            <<<<< URL does not match
                                                           |
                                                           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is it because I am not including Headers in the matchers?

If yes, how can I avoid matching the headers? I would like to get a response irrespective of what header I am sending.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Found the reason.. `WireMock.urlPathEqualTo("/test/url?bookingCode=XYZ123&lastName=TEST")` should not have query params.

Changing it to `WireMock.urlPathEqualTo("/test/url")` resolved the issue.

[Documentation](http://wiremock.org/docs/stubbing/) says it is allowed. Also, the log `URL does not match` was causing the confusion. Considering the match check is separate, wiremock could have added a separate log for query param.

Created issue : https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/issues/1262

Comment: Try changing the method to urlEqualTo in place of urlPathEqualTo.

Answer (score 19):

You can go with `withQueryParam` method for the parameters while keeping `urlPathEqualTo` method dedicated to URL path.

```
WireMock.stubFor(WireMock.get(WireMock.urlPathEqualTo("/test/url"))
         .withQueryParam("bookingCode", WireMock.equalTo("XYZ123"))
         .withQueryParam("lastName", WireMock.equalTo("TEST"))
         .willReturn(WireMock.aResponse()
         .withStatus(200))
```

For more information, please refer http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/

Answer (score -1):

You should escape the regex special character "?"

```
WireMock.stubFor(WireMock.get(WireMock.urlPathEqualTo("/test/url\\?bookingCode=XYZ123&lastName=TEST"))
    .willReturn(WireMock.aResponse()
    .withStatus(200))
)
```

Comment: Escaping character "?" dont' work with wiremock 2.25.1 , but withQueryParam do.